# nginx-ingress - https configuration - server IP address could not be found

Tags: lets-encrypt, nginx-ingress, google-cloud-dns, cert-manager

I want to enable https for my web app, hosted in GKE. I have a domain name, arindam.fr and DNS name is mentioned in Cloud DNS, and got NS for Type A.

I am getting error:

This site can’t be reached arindam.fr’s server IP address could not be found.

when accessing page: https://arindam.fr/

https://github.com/arindam-b/DNSissue/blob/master/3.png

https://github.com/arindam-b/DNSissue/blob/master/1.PNG "Cloud DNS"

My Deployment & Service yaml:

My ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - arindam.fr
    secretName: tls-staging-cert
  rules:
  - host: arindam.fr
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-app
          servicePort: 8080
```

Before that I installed nginx controller and cert manager using helm:

```
helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress
```

Domain's NS are mentioned in my domain registration, in namecheap.com

https://github.com/arindam-b/DNSissue/blob/master/2.PNG "NS Configuration"

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-app        
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-app
          image: "eu.gcr.io/rcup-mza-dev/hello-app:latest"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          livenessProbe:
                httpGet:
                    path: /
                    port: 8080
                initialDelaySeconds: 15
                timeoutSeconds: 30 
          readinessProbe:
                httpGet:
                    path: /
                    port: 8080
                initialDelaySeconds: 15
                timeoutSeconds: 30
---                
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP       
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-app    
    #  type: LoadBalancer
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNSSEC was turned off, so it was not properly propagating. After turning it on it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you registar's configuration is not propagating correctly Google's nameservers, I just check it in the following [link](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/). I also found this [guide](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/767/10/how-to-change-dns-for-a-domain) for how to change NS in namecheap, take in mind that you need to select "custom DNS" option to specify Google's NS.

After your registar propagates correctly the nameservers, this could take between 24-72 hours, you will be able to reach your domain.

Comment: Thank you. I make changes, waiting for it to propagate.